# Is running WCF service outside IIS quicker?

Tags: c#, wcf

I appreciate that this question could come across like a weak question and shows no research effort on my part.

But,I can assure you i have spent quite a lot of time trying to find out this answer.

On one side I get the answer that IIS does a lot of the 'plumbing' and is therefore quicker and on the other side I get that because IIS does a lot of the 'plumbing' it adds an overhead and is slower.

My app is very simple: it is a c# desktop app that uploads jpegs as byte arrays as often and as quickly as possibly. Each byte arrays is small - 18KBs and as soon as it gets to my server it is saved to the hard drive.

I do not wait for a response back from my server to the client. The operation is a 'one-way-contract'.

So far all I get its: 'it should be quicker' etc.  What I want to find out is why it is quicker.

Thanks

Comment: For some more info, have you tested if it is quicker going the standalone WCF instead of the IIS method?

Comment: Yes, i had consider a speed test.  But i was after the facts of the matter.  i have been asked by my boss to put forward a case for using and not using IIS.  I have not got the luxury of relying on speed tests. They want the facts as to WHY..

Comment: Whats the existing motivation to move outside of IIS?  Is it currently too slow?  If thats the case, have you edited the ConcurrencyMode of the service?  The default is Single, meaning the service will process one request at time.  You could switch the mode to Multiple, allowing multiple simultaneous requests to processed.  Of course, this means your service is now multi-threaded.

Comment: @LaurenceAdams hi, thanks for such a great comment.  I have not considered that.  However, is there a limit to the number of threads? Also, my motivation is to quicken the upload process. Obviously, i cannot make the internet quicker so I am looking elsewhere/anywhere. The quicker i can upload the faster FPS rate I will attain

Comment: @LaurenceAdams Just realized I had already enabled this! lol. Been a year since i looked at this code :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Excellent.  The maximum varies from system to system, and can be controlled with the ServiceThrottle class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.servicethrottle.aspx

Comment: @LaurenceAdams Thanks for the link. i already throttle my request so gr8 minds think alike :). Would you know though would I gain anything from hosting outside IIS and/or using tcp binding instead of basicbinding?